# jQuery validate require_from_group is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using require _from_group i n my from for validation but it is not working.

My script  code is HERE:

jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: true,
         $(document).ready(function () {

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});

$("#findproject_form").validate({
    rules: {
        Profession: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
        },
        Location1: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
        },
        Company: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
        },
        Name: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
        },
        KeyWord: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".validategroup"]
        }
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function (value, element, options) {
    var $fields = $(options[1], element.form),
        $fieldsFirst = $fields.eq(0),
        validator = $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") ? $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") : $.extend({}, this),
        isValid = $fields.filter(function () {
            return validator.elementValue(this);
        }).length >= options[0];

    // Store the cloned validator for future validation
    $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp", validator);

    // If element isn't being validated, run each require_from_group field's validation rules
    if (!$(element).data("being_validated")) {
        $fields.data("being_validated", true);
        $fields.each(function () {
            validator.element(this);
        });
        $fields.data("being_validated", false);
    }
    return isValid;
}, $.validator.format("Please fill at least {0} of these fields."));
```

});

It gives error when any one or more field are fill_out instead of when it is empty and not goto the action page.
So what is wrong in that.

MY FORM IS HERE

```
 <form id="findproject_form" method="post"  action="{$BASE_URL}findproject" >
        <div class="bgtrans"><h3>Search By</h3>
        <div class="div_bg1">
        <div class="searchbg"><div class="seachbginputbg"><input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Profession" id="Profession" name="Profession" value="{if $profession}{$profession|escape}{/if}" /></div></div>
        <div class="searchbg"><div class="seachbginputbg"><input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Location" id="Location1" name="Location1" value="{if $location}{$location|escape}{/if}" /></div></div>
        <div class="searchbg" style="margin-right:0px;">
        <div class="seachbginputbg"><input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Company" id="Company" name="Company"  value="{if $company}{$company|escape}{/if}"/></div>

         </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div_bg2">
        <div class="searchbg"><div class="seachbginputbg"><input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="Name" name="Name" value="{if $name}{$name|escape}{/if}" /></div></div>
        <div class="searchbg"><div class="seachbginputbg"><input class="seachbginput validategroup" type="text" placeholder="Key Words" id="KeyWord" name="KeyWord" value="{if $keyword}{$keyword|escape}{/if}"/></div></div>
        <div class="searchbg" style="margin-right:0px;">
        <input  class="bgbttn" type="submit" name="submit" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>               
        </div>
```

Comment: Don't you need to add your method before trying to validate against it?

Comment: If I remove it gives error: exception occured when checking element Location1, check the 'require_from_group' method

Comment: That's **not** the `require_from_group` function... [that's just sample code from the `addMethod` documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

Answer (score 2):

**Remove your custom method.** *(It makes the field optional and it's comparing the value of your field to the sum of your parameters.  Since your parameters are the number `1` and a class name, clearly, this makes no sense.)*...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1];
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please fill out atleast one field "));
```

That does not make sense because that's not really the `require_from_group` function... [that's just some sample code from the `.addMethod()` documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) with the name changed into `"require_from_group"`.

---

Use the default version of `require_from_group` method/rule included within [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js).  You can include the whole file or copy the one method below.

As you can see, this is not a trivial function.

```
$.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
    var $fields = $(options[1], element.form),
        $fieldsFirst = $fields.eq(0),
        validator = $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") ? $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") : $.extend({}, this),
        isValid = $fields.filter(function() {
            return validator.elementValue(this);
        }).length >= options[0];

    // Store the cloned validator for future validation
    $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp", validator);

    // If element isn't being validated, run each require_from_group field's validation rules
    if (!$(element).data("being_validated")) {
        $fields.data("being_validated", true);
        $fields.each(function() {
            validator.element(this);
        });
        $fields.data("being_validated", false);
    }
    return isValid;
}, $.validator.format("Please fill at least {0} of these fields."));
```

**DEMO (with your jQuery and HTML):  http://jsfiddle.net/y3qayufu/2/**

Comment: I added method as above in additional-methods.js, but still getting same error

Comment: I updated code, but it's not working. also I upload code here in question. I am using this form in smarty template file

Comment: @HarshGandhi, 1) As you can see in my jsFiddle link, the jQuery code you posted is working fine.  2) We need to see the HTML as the browser sees it, not the server... so please post the ***rendered*** HTML.  3)  Why not just look at the HTML markup in my jsFiddle to see how yours is broken?

Comment: @HarshGandhi, and 4) here is ***your code*** in a jsFiddle and it's working properly:  http://jsfiddle.net/y3qayufu/2/